# sending report to person if they have a task to do

Tags: powerbi

On PowerBI I have a report where there are tasks needed to be done and I want to send the filtered version of the report per person to the email address. Also, the person may not have a task at all so they should not receive any emails at all. Is this even possible to do so? I have Alerts are a thing and potentially use that but it is not really a tidy way of doing what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Power BI doesn't support data driven subscriptions to the reports. In [SSRS you can do this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-data-driven-subscription-ssrs-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver15), so the user gets a report based on the data.

There is a work around [here](https://angryanalyticsblog.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2017/11/13/data-driven-subscriptions-in-power-bi/), that allows you only to send the hyperlink of the report, that may meet some of your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this. In the light of recent Microsoft Business Application Summit, is there any way of doing this now? I see Paginated Power BI reports are available but only for Power BI Premium users which cannot be justified for $5000 per month.